# What is the cause of "Latex Error: The font size command /normalsize is not defined"

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I follow the instructions online to set up environment for LaTeX using Sublime text 3 and skim. However, I encountered a problem. When I try to compile the latex document shown in the picture, there are a lot of errors shown and the PDF generated is blank, i.e. without the "Introduction: ..." line.

[image: Screenshot of ST3]

And I downloaded all relevant program including `latexmk`.

[image: System Check in ST3]

Is there anything I can do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should use

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
```

not

```
\document[a4paper]{article}
```

Also, regarding the use of `$$`...`$$` for display math, see [Why is `\[` ... `\]` preferable to `$$` ... `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5764)